# Compiler can't find Graphics.hpp?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

main.cpp:

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

enviroment variables:

PATH:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin 
C:\SFML-2.6.1\include
```

but it keeps saying to console:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

i just don't know what to do yet. I was trying to write path via "/" but it still doesn't work, though.

folders of C disk:

[folders of C disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF9YQ.png)

Comment: You need to tell it where you installed `SFML` with `-I` for header files `-I<directory_above_SFML>` and you most probably need to do the same for libraries with `-L` and tell it where the libraries are.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is for the OS to search for **executables**, and only executables. It won't help your compiler find header files nor your linker find library files. The way you have written your `include`, there should be a `SFML` folder next to `main.cpp` with `Graphics.hpp` inside it, although the way it exactly works depends on your compiler. Read more about `#include`s on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include): see explanation #2 for the quoted char includes like the one you typed.

Comment: You should use some build manger or build manager generator. I would recommend use cmake.

Comment: If you are using msys2 to install MinGW use pacman to install `sfml` then you don't need to set any include or library directories and also you will have the correct sfml binaries for your compiler and not ones that were built with msvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `g++` command line, add the flag `-I...` like this: `g++ -I C:\SFML-2.6.1\include`, and try again. (It doesn't matter whether there is a space after `-I`.) Alternatively, you may set the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment value to `C:\SFML-2.6.1\include`.

After it succeeds, you will likely get an error from the linker. To fix that, set a library path for linking. That may look something like `g++ -L C:\SFML-2.6.1\lib`. Alternatively set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to `C:\SFML-2.6.1\lib`.